# Broken pagination

Tags: pagination, loop, customization

Well I'm here again with almost the same problem as I had in [this post three weeks ago](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37431/broken-pagination-need-help-figuring-out-why/37435#37435), but let me explain what has happened since then:

I was originally using one loop to display the most recent sticky post at the top of the front page, then a second loop to display every other post (except for all other stickies). Here's my code as it stands now:

```
// first loop to display only my single, MOST RECENT sticky post
$sticky = get_option('sticky_posts');
$wp_query = new WP_Query(array('post__in' => $sticky, 'caller_get_posts' => 1, 'orderby' => ID, 'showposts' => 1)); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <!-- loop code -->
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>

// second loop to display every other post, excluding sticky posts
<?php query_posts(array('post__not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts'))); // exclude all sticky posts ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <!-- loop code -->
<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

What is happening here is perfect...for the front page only. I get my nice single/most-recent sticky post at the very top, followed by another 5 posts. Unfortunately, if I page over to the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc pages - all I see are the same 5 posts that were under the sticky post on the front page!

I'm quite new with the concept of multiple loops, so I could really use a hand here!

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few issues that are probably contributing to your issue:

1. Only ever use `query_posts()` to modify the primary Loop.
2. The [`caller_get_posts` parameter has been deprecated](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Sticky_Post_Parameters), in favor of `ignore_sticky_posts`
3. The `$wp_query` variable is a defined global. Using it outside of its intended use may cause unintended circumstances.

So, first, you need to determine which is your primary Loop. I will assume this to be the **second** loop.

Second, come up with a unique, descriptive name for your secondary loop (i.e. your **first** loop), such as `$most_recent_sticky_post`.

That should leave you with:

```
<?php
// Get IDs of sticky posts
$sticky = get_option('sticky_posts');
// first loop to display only my single, 
// MOST RECENT sticky post
$most_recent_sticky_post = new WP_Query( array( 
    // Only sticky posts
    'post__in' => $sticky, 
    // Treat them as sticky posts
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 0, 
    // Order by ID
    'orderby' => ID, 
    // Get only the one most recent
    'showposts' => 1
) );
while ( $most_recent_sticky_post->have_posts() ) : $most_recent_sticky_post->the_post(); ?>
    <!-- loop code -->
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>

// second loop to display every other post, 
// excluding sticky posts
<?php 
query_posts( array( 
    // exclude all sticky posts
    'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) 
) );  
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <!-- loop code -->
<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Now, since you're no longer stomping on `$wp_query`, your pagination *should* work properly.

#### Edit

Okay, other things:

1. The `showposts` parameter is *also* deprecated. Use `post_per_page` instead.
2. Let's try [doing a *merge* of query variables](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Usage_Note) for your primary loop.

e.g.:

```
// Define custom query args
$custom_query_args = array( 
    // exclude all sticky posts
    'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) 
);  
// globalize $wp_query
global $wp_query;
// Merge custom args with default query args
$merged_query_args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, $custom_query_args );
// process the query
query_posts( $merged_query_args );
```

I don't know that this will make a difference, but I prefer to modify the default query using this method.

1. If that still doesn't work, then force `query_posts()` to remember that it's supposed to use paging. Add `'paged' => get_query_var('paged')` to your `$custom_query_args` array:

e.g.

```
  // Define custom query args
  $custom_query_args = array( 
      // exclude all sticky posts
      'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
      // don't forget to paginate!
      'paged' => get_query_var('paged')
  );
```

Where does that get us?

Comment: Chip! I'm a big fan of your work in the WordPress community!

Now, I've edited my code to match what you posted _exactly_, but there are two problems: 

1) On the front page, all of my sticky posts are showing (if have 3 at the moment) and I only want the most recent one to show.
2) Pagination still doesn't work :( I probably should have mentioned this earlier, but I'm using the WP-PageNavi plugin to meet my pagination needs since I haven't learned how to code my own pagination - but that's a project for another time :P

Comment: You can ignore #2, Wp-PageNavi is not causing the problem. I deactivated the plugin and added the next_posts_link/previous_posts_link code, but pagination is still broken.

Comment: That did it! You're the man Chip, thank you so much for your help :) I'm hardly more than a novice when it comes to not-so-simple PHP, so your tips made the difference! Pagination works, and only my most recent sticky post is showing at the top of the front page only - perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using paging parameters in your WP_Query

```
 $posts = new WP_Query( array( /*your args here*/, 'paged' => get_query_var( 'page' ) ) );
```

It could be get_query_var( 'paged' ) depending on WP version I believe.

[WP_Query pagination parameters here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters)

Comment: Neither worked. I thought I'd give it a shot, even though I haven't seen that solution anywhere else.

Comment: I believe `paged` and `page` refer to different things, `page` refers to a paginated post(`<!--nextpage-->`), `paged` refers to paging for archival views(category, date, author, etc...).